# Showing $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{D}}{2}]$ is a subring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $D\equiv 1 \ \textrm{mod}\ 4$. It's straightforward that this is closed under subtraction. To show multiplication however, I'm not entirely sure how to proceed:
\begin{align*}
\left(a+b\frac{1+\sqrt{D}}{2}\right)\left(x+y\frac{1+\sqrt{D}}{2}\right)=\left(ax+\frac{1}{4}by(1+D)\right)+(ay+bx+by)\frac{1+\sqrt{D}}{2}
\end{align*}

But this first term on the RHS is not necessarily an integer. For example, if $D=5$ (which is congruent to 1 modular 4) then I don't get an integer for $a=c=d=1$. There is probably a stupid mistake somewhere. Thanks in advance for pointing it out.

Edit: notation error with $x$'s and $y$'s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\rho=\frac{1+\sqrt D}2$. This number is such that $\rho^2=\rho+\frac{D-1}4 $. Can you take it from here?

Comment: So, $(a+b\rho)(x+y\rho)=(ax+\frac{1}{4}by(\rho+\frac{D-1}{4})+(ay+bx)\rho^2$. Then since $D\equiv 1$ $\frac{D-1}{4}$ must be an integer. And so the $by$ goes with the $\rho$ (I for some reason assumed it was already there?). Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, this isn't quite right what I meant was that I get $ax+ay\rho+bx\rho+by\rho^2=ax+by(\rho+\frac{D-1}{4})+(ay+bx)\rho$, which give $(ax+by(\frac{D-1}{4}))+(ay+bx+by)\rho$